# Save information that was spied by Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a JUnit test as:

```
@Spy
ParallelSender parallelSender = new ParallelSender();


@Test
public void send() {   
    // making some data...
    parallelSender.send(someData);
    // check that internal method has been called with Sender Task made from someData
    verify(parallelSender).doSend(any(SenderTask.class));
}
```

I however like to examine that SenderTask contains all the fields exactly as I need them. Can I tell the spy to intercept the *doSend* call, store its parameters in some array and then continue to real method?

Comment: yes - [use argument captor](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
@Test
public void send() {   
    // making some data...
    parallelSender.send(someData);

   // Define the captor for class
    ArgumentCaptor<SenderTask> captor =
        ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SenderTask.class);

    // Capture input while verifying
    verify(parallelSender).doSend(captor.capture());

    // Assert 
    SomeTask result = captor.getValue();
    // assertions on result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArgumentCaptor`.

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<SenderTask> captor;
// or ArgumentCaptor<SenderTask> captor = 
//         ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SenderTask.class);

@Test public void send() {
    // ...
    verify(parallelSender).doSend(captor.capture());
    SenderTask captured = captor.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use argument captor because it's usually not necessary.
Just do this

```
@Test
public void send() {   
    //given
    SomeData myInput = ...
    SenderTask expectedOutput = new SenderTask();
    expectedOutput.setSomeField(/*expected field value*/);

    //when
    parallelSender.send(myInput);

    //then
    verify(parallelSender).doSend(expectedOutput);
 }
```

The idea behind is to check that "doSend" was called with an expected object.

Note: just make sure that you implemented equals/hash method in SenderTask - or it will not work

Note2: I would suggest avoiding using any() in your unit tests. Usually when your are unit-testing something - you want to be as much precise as possible. So use concrete objects during results verification.

Hopefully it helps

Comment: that is also a good approach, providing you can guess exact values in test. Though I have to accept other answer as it more aligned with inital question.